# Localisation of Page Titles with laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, localization, laravel-blade

I have the main page where I yield the title like this:

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
```

Now I want to use this on my pages, but I want it to be localized, so I have the lang folder with two languages - en & ru, inside of which I have a file called 'titles.php', where I keep my titles.

The problem is that if I try to use something like

```
@section('title', {{__('titles.faq')}})
```

on my page it throws an error immediately. Is there any way to do that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this @section('title', __('titles.faq'))  without {{ }} https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization#retrieving-translation-strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use the curly brackets in a blade function, they are evaluated as plain php code:

```
@section('title', __('titles.faq'))
```